# "Singularity or stiff system suspected" and "Input value lies outside of range" errors when plotting complex pendulum

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

This is my first time posting a question so apologies for any issues.

I'm a first year physics student who just started using mathematica last week. Part of my physics course is to create a computer model of a complex pendulum. 
My pendulum is based off the angry arms exhibit from Questacon https://www.questacon.edu.au/visiting/galleries/wonderworks/exhibits/angry-arms

Essentially you have a solid T-Bar which rotates around the intersection. This t-bar then has 3 pendulums off the edge of each arm.

To model this, I defined the legrangian and Euler-legrangian of the system. I then used ndsolve to find the solutions to the differential equation, and used that solution to plot it.

Euler-Legrange Calculation:

```
(*The height and velocity of the bob of a pendulum, given then angle of the pendulum and the angle of the tbar*)
h[\[Theta]_, \[Theta]tbar_,t_] = dt*(1 - Cos[\[Theta]tbar[t]]) + dp*(1 - Cos[\[Theta][t]]);
v[\[Theta]_, \[Theta]tbar_,t_] = \[Theta]tbar'[t]*((dp*Sin[\[Theta][t]])^2 + (dt - dp*Cos[\[Theta][t]])^2)^(1/2) + \[Theta][t]*dp;
(*The total Kinetic Energy (U) and Potential Energy (V) of the system*)
U[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_, \[Theta]3_, \[Theta]4_, t_] = 1/2 m*(v[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]4, t]^2 + v[\[Theta]2, \[Theta]4, t]^2 + v[\[Theta]3, \[Theta]4, t]^2);
V[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_, \[Theta]3_, \[Theta]4_, t_] = m*g*(h[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]4, t] + h[\[Theta]2, \[Theta]4, t] + h[\[Theta]3, \[Theta]4, t]);
(*The calculation of the Legrangian and Euler-Legrangian*)
L[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_, \[Theta]3_, \[Theta]4_, t_] = U[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2, \[Theta]3, \[Theta]4, t] - V[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2, \[Theta]3, \[Theta]4, t];
el = EulerEquations[L[\[Theta]l, \[Theta]r, \[Theta]m, \[Theta]t,t], {\[Theta]l[t], \[Theta]r[t], \[Theta]m[t], \[Theta]t[t]}, t];
```

Solving Euler-Legrange

```
Clear[\[Theta]l,\[Theta]r,\[Theta]m,\[Theta]t,dt,dp,g,m,tMax,nFrames]
pm = dt {Sin[\[Theta]t[t]], -Cos[\[Theta]t[t]]};
pl = dt {Sin[\[Theta]t[t] - N[Pi/2]], -Cos[\[Theta]t[t] - N[Pi/2]]};
pr = dt {Sin[\[Theta]t[t] + N[Pi/2]], -Cos[\[Theta]t[t] + N[Pi/2]]};
ppm = pm + dp {Sin[\[Theta]m[t]], -Cos[\[Theta]m[t]]};
ppr = pr + dp {Sin[\[Theta]r[t]], -Cos[\[Theta]r[t]]};
ppl = pl + dp {Sin[\[Theta]l[t]], -Cos[\[Theta]l[t]]};
dt = 1;
dp = 1/2;
g = 9.8;
m = 1;
tMax = 20;
initial = {\[Theta]l[0] == Pi/3, \[Theta]r[0] == 0, \[Theta]m[0] == 0, \[Theta]t[0] == Pi/2};
sol = First[NDSolve[Join[el,initial], {\[Theta]l[t], \[Theta]r[t], \[Theta]m[t], \[Theta]t[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}], Method -> Shooting]
```

Modelling

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{ppl, ppr, ppm} /. sol],{t, 0, tMax},PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> {"Trajectory of leftmost pendulum", "Trajectory of rightmost pendulum", "Trajectory of middle pendulum"}]

nFrames = tMax*20;
frames = Table[Graphics[{
  Gray, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, pl, ppl}], Line[{{0, 0}, pm, ppm}], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, pr, ppr}],
  Darker[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1],
  Darker[Red], Disk[pr, 0.1], Disk[ppr, 0.1],
  Darker[Blue], Disk[pl, 0.1], Disk[ppl, 0.1],
  Darker[Green], Disk[pm, 0.1], Disk[ppm, 0.1]
  } /. sol, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
Background -> Lighter[Cyan]
],{t, tMax/nFrames, tMax, tMax/nFrames}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

For some initial values (usually having everything but [\theta]t 0) the parametric plot and simulation both work perfectly and the only error I get is:

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.
```

For other initial values (Having more non zero initial values) the plot still runs alright but the pendulums aren't where I expect them and I get the additional error

```
NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended
```

Finally for some seemingly random initial values, the parametric plot becomes a crazy ball, and the simulation freaks out. I also get:

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.00453348, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {1/20} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
InterpolatingFunction::dprec: The precision of input value {161/20} and/or the interpolation grid is insufficient to compute the value.
```

Note, the t value and input value number change depending on the initial values.

I've looked around for a solution but haven't been able to find anything.
If you have any idea's let me know.

Comment: Needs["VariationalMethods`"] is missing from code.

Comment: Apologies, I had that at the top of the code, just forgot to copy paste it into the question